# Why do I still have strings in my ListBox even after using a loop to individually remove them?

Tags: c++, mfc, listbox

Stumbled across what seems like an odd bug..... I have ListBox items added with addstring ... I have the listbox control return a count as a `DWORD` and convert it into an integer with the following code and only a portion of the strings listed are deleted ... I realise some of the type conversions arent necessary, but i have tried without the typecasting and the issue remains the same....the code :

```
int count = (int)myListBox->GetListBoxInfo();
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= count; cnt++) {
        UINT itemIndex = (UINT)cnt;
        myListBox->DeleteString(itemIndex);

    }
    myListBox->UpdateData();
    myListBox->UpdateWindow();
```

I’m sure there is probably another way to clear the list but im curious why this isn't working ....

Kind regards stackoverflow,

Comment: `myListBox->ResetContent();` Just saying.

Comment: @WhozCraig cheers mate, will try that now.... any idea why only a fraction of the strings are deleted ??

Comment: Yeah, because each time you clear a string you're reducing the item count (and thus the index limits) of the listbox. I.e. the item at `1` becomes the item at `0` when you delete the item at `0` prior. `myListBox->DeleteString(0);` repeated `count` times would do what you seem to be trying. Hope that made sense.

Comment: @WhozCraig makes sense, thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your listbox as

```
0  foo
1  bar
2  baz
```

Now, hit your loop. Delete index 0:

```
0  bar
1  baz
```

Now delete index 1

```
0  bar
```

See the problem? This would do what you want:

```
int count = (int)myListBox->GetListBoxInfo();
for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
    myListBox->DeleteString(0);

myListBox->UpdateData();
myListBox->UpdateWindow();
```

But in reality, belay all of that and just do this:

```
myListBox->ResetContent();
```

See [`ResetContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistbox-class?view=vs-2019#resetcontent) in the MSDN Library.

Comment: awesome, thank you very much... I was going to remove this stackoverflow entry but your answer is clear and concise and could benefit others... thanks :)